# Targeting an element using the :not pseudoclass

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target some headers except those within a particular parent element. When I apply the styles below to the (abstracted) HTML below, the font size of both headers is impacted. What do I have wrong with the `:not` selector?

In this scenario I'm not able to modify the CSS selectors but need to make sure the HTML is crafted such that the selectors work as expected.

```css
:not(#beginning) h4.small {
  font-size: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="beginning">
  <h4 class="small">Unaffected header</h4>
</div>

<div id="end">
  <h4 class="small">Affected header</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `:not(#beginning) > h4.small` instead. Your `h4.small` will always be a descendant *somewhere* within an element that doesn’t have the ID `beginning`. You want to select `h4.small` elements that aren’t *children* of the `#beginning` element.

```css
:not(#beginning) > h4.small {
  font-size: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="beginning">
  <h4 class="small">Unaffected header</h4>
</div>

<div id="end">
  <h4 class="small">Affected header</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also recommend using `div:not(#beginning) > h4.small`. From what I understand that would be much more performant as it doesn't have to check the `:not` against every element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this context I can't change the CSS selector - I need to work the HTML to work within the selector provided. If I understand your point, the h4.small inside div#beginning would still be affected because that h4 is still within some _other_ element that does not have the id of beginning. Is that right? That being the case, and bearing in mind the constraint on changing the CSS, I'm not sure how to craft an HTML structure that will have the CSS target the second header but not the first.

Comment: @justinraczak There’s no valid HTML to match this selector. Why can’t you change it? Where does it come from?

Comment: It's part of an exercise for a class. I'm given the CSS selectors and need to craft HTML that would be selected by it. I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to figure out how to do it before turning to SO :/

Comment: Then the answer is going to be no markup. If your instructor knows what they're teaching. Or they made a mistake and need to change the selector to what's mentioned in this answer.